# Token From Different Server Causing Continuous Crashes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

We have an ASP.NET Core application which has the default authentication system and is hosted on Azure.
Recently, we created a new AppService and routed the users to that service while maintaining connection to the same database.

However, when users use the new server, we get continuous crashes with the following error:

> The key {xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx} was not found in the key ring.

of type

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException

and method

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenSerializer.Deserialize(String
>   serializedToken)

Our understanding is that the server is trying to decrypt the token but since it was received from a different server, our server just crashes.

We would so much appreciate if you can suggest a way to solve this issue temporarily until we change the DataProtection provider.

We want a way that wouldn't let our server crash.

Thank you so much

Update: I'm surprised now that this error happens in: POST Account/Login and POST Account/Register while these methods do not require authorization, however these methods are decorated with:

> [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

Both Get Account/Login and Post Account/Login happen on the same server.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have machine key same across the farm. You should set it at the application level, meaning, different apps have different keys but the same app has the same key on all server of the farm.

The machine mey is responsible for encrypting some internals of selected features of the engine, including the antiforgery tokens. A different key on different servers causes the exact issue you describe.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/amb/2012/07/31/easiest-way-to-generate-machinekey/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Hi, we're actually using Azure, is there a way to achieve that? thank you

Comment: I believe that the machine key should be the same. The weird thing is that login is working fine but we're getting a lot of exceptions in the log... perhaps these exceptions resulted from users previously logged-in from a different machine

Answer (score 0):

In my case.
This error happened as I was using two or more instances for the identity server.

So,
Login goes fine but checking the token cause errors.
As the login was done by an instance and checking was done using other instance.

**The easiest way to solve this is to make sure that your identity server or API is using only one instance.**